# Pledge payment link does not point to a publicly accessible page

Tags: wordpress, message-templates, civipledge

The reminder email for pledge payments includes a link that points to a page on the admin side of wordpress that requires a login. How can I change this setting in CiviPledge to point to a publicly accessible page?

[Here's a sample of the link](https://lofcenter.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1&cid=3305&pledgeId=5&cs=da386e473e8c85e6d2f948217cc28625_1451424231_168)

[image: Pledge Payment Reminder]

In response to comments below:

1 - I am using the default message template for Payment Reminders.

2 - The Old/New Base URL in Settings - Cleanup Caches and Paths shows "https://lofcenter.org/"

3 - The civicrm.settings.php shows the following: 
if (!defined('CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL')) {
  define( 'CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL'      , 'https://lofcenter.org/' );

Comment: Thank you, Jorge, for the added info.  Do any other Civi email messages create links with the additional "admin-only" info in the URL?  Put another way, do any of your other templates that use the 'crmURL' token create the same problem?  I know one template that uses 'crmURL' is the Contribution Receipt - online.

Comment: Another idea: could you send a test message to yourself using the 'crmURL' token and see what happens with the link?

Comment: My apologies, I've sent an email from CiviCRM to myself using {crmURL} in the message body and I receive {crmURL} in the email, no link.

Comment: Hey @AllenHutchison, I did try an online contribution and the only link in the email was to "tell a friend" that link is https://lofcenter.org/CiviCRM?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1  Pledge Payment reminders still point to a login page instead of the pledge payment page. Any other ways to trouble shoot this?

Answer (score 1):

*This answer is for how to change the template issuing the email in question.  However, I don't know that the issue you're facing is due to the template.  See other answer.*

The template for Pledge Payment Reminders is found in Communications or CiviMail's settings.

From the black menu bar:

> Administer > Communications > Message Templates

OR

> Administer > CiviMail > Message Templates

**On the Message Templates screen, click on the tab at the top for "System Workflow Messages."  Scroll down and you should see an edit link for "Pledges - Payment Reminder."**

On that edit screen, you can make any changes you need including changing the link.  Don't forget to make your changes in both the HTML Format and Plain-Text Format.

Before making your changes, I'd recommend copying and pasting the default template to a text document just to have it saved in case you need to revert back in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the issue to make sure I understand it:

Your example checksum link is as follows:

```
https://lofcenter.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1&cid=3305&pledgeId=5&cs=da386e473e8c85e6d2f948217cc28625_1451424231_168
```

The example Wordpress checksum link per [Tokens](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Tokens) on the CiviCRM wiki appears as:

```
http://www.myorganization.org/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=N&{contact.checksum}&cid={contact.contact_id}
```

If you are using the default message template for Payment Reminders (*please let us know as an Edit in your answer if it is somehow different*), here is the relevant template code with tokens:

```
{if $contribution_page_id}
     {capture assign=contributionUrl}{crmURL p='civicrm/contribute/transact' q="reset=1&id=`$contribution_page_id`&cid=`$contact.contact_id`&pledgeId=`$pledge_id`&cs=`$checksumValue`" a=true h=0}{/capture}
     <p><a href="{$contributionUrl}">{ts}Go to a web page where you can make your payment online{/ts}</a></p>
{else}
     <p>{ts}Please mail your payment to{/ts}: {$domain.address}</p>
{/if}
```

**So, the extra bit getting inserted into your `crmURL` token is: `wp-admin/admin.php`**  The remainder of your checksum link seems to line up as it should.

Could you please verify (and report back as an Edit in your question):

1. What is listed for your Old and New Base URL on Administer > System Settings > Cleanup Caches and Update Paths?\
2. What your Base URL is listed as in your civicrm.settings.php file?

Per the [Wordpress install instructions, Step 6](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/WordPress+Installation+Guide+for+CiviCRM+4.5#WordPressInstallationGuideforCiviCRM4.5-6.LocateandBackuptheCiviCRMsettingsfile), the civicrm.settings.php file is located here: `<wordpress>/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php`

The relevant line will have something akin to:  `define( 'CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL' , 'https://lofcenter.org/');`

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to mark this as answered/fix because the latest batch of reminders did work. The link sent with the Pledge Payment reminder works as of today, here's a copy of the link that the crmURL shows, for an unknown reason it does not have the extra wp-admin/admin.php bit.

https://lofcenter.org/CiviCRM/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1&cid=3305&pledgeId=5&cs=c8321de782a6e8fb19ce9305f9a2ffe4_1452834091_336

Comment: Glad to hear it's resolved!